# How to recovery deleted post on Tor.SE?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have no idea why someone delete my question:

https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/torcoin-the-real-way-to-make-tor-rich

I'm trying to recovery text, to rebuild it somehow to send to arma. I discovery for myself that there is no cache. Google cache too empty, archive.org - empty.

Every other stackexchange's branchs keeps deleted post for user, to have option to rebuild it.

Could somebody provide me with solution around stackexchange, How can I retrive my question([post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/torcoin-the-real-way-to-make-tor-rich)) in raw text?

---

Looks like something works wrong:

I'm ask the same question on tor.stackexchange.com, than delete it, there is nothing in the `deleted recent answers`

> Deleted Recent Answers
>
> No deleted recent answers

https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1030

On my personal page.

And nothing in the `questions`

Answer (score 3):

You question was down-voted and closed as unclear what you're asking by Feb, 3rd. The [Community](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) decided to delete the question ten days later. Thatswhy you couldn't see it anymore. I copied the text to a [paste](http://paste.debian.net/89474/). Please load the text from this site. I hope this helps you to move your proposal forward.

Comment: I'm asking about stackexchange default functionality. This should be available in my personal page, is not?